# Scrolldown Listview from top

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview

I am having one `ImageView` and below this `ImageView`, I am having one `ListView`. I want to scroll down the `ListView` from top and Zoom the `ImageView` when `ListView` scrolls down. Can anyone help ?

Basically, I want to zoom the `ImageView` which is on top of `ListView` when someone pulls the `ListView` from top.

Comment: If I interpreted correctly ,you can use `ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()` to find out how far down the list view you are. And use this as a condition for your imageView height which you can set programatically using `getLayoutParams()`.

Comment: ImageView and ListView both are in 50-50 space vertically. The LIstView is already on top and i want to scroll it down. Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding... So you have an ImageView and a ListView. Does the ListView scroll properly? Is it functioning? If so, you can determine how far down the list view you scrolled and resize the imageView accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

ListView and ScrollView with pull to zoom : https://github.com/Frank-Zhu/PullZoomView

Comment: Thanks. But my ImageView is fixed on Top. It can't be scrolled up.